# Using the parent() function to add an extra attribute

Tags: jquery, parent

I'm trying to add an `attr` based on a class name by using the `parent()` function.

My code is as follows:

```
<div class="kiwi-topbar-nav">
    <div class="uk-container">

    <nav class="uk-navbar-container uk-navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="uk-navbar-toggle uk-search-icon" href="#">toggle</a></li>
            <li>...</li>        
        </ul>
    </nav>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="kiwi-main-nav">
    <div class="uk-container">

    <nav class="uk-navbar-container uk-navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="uk-navbar-toggle uk-search-icon" href="#">toggle</a></li>
            <li>...</li>        
        </ul>
    </nav>

    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.uk-navbar-container.uk-navbar').each(function() {

   $toggle = $('.uk-navbar-toggle.uk-search-icon');

  if ( $(this).parent('.kiwi-topbar-nav') ) { 
     $toggle.attr('target', '.kiwi-topbar-nav');
  } else if ( $(this).parent('.kiwi-main-nav') ) {
     $toggle.attr('target', '.kiwi-main-nav');
  } 

});
```

I noticed that the attr. `target="kiwi-topbar-nav"` is added inside both the `kiwi-topbar-nav` and `kiwi-main-nav div`. While depending on the parent div name it should have different attributes. Am I misunderstanding the `parent()` function? And if in case I am, which other jquery function should I use instead?

Comment: `.parent()` returns an object which is always [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/truthy)

Comment: have you tried with .parents() function?

Comment: Try closest not parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$toggle` is all elements with both classes, you need to change it to be the one with regards to the current one in the each loop:

```js
$('.uk-navbar-container.uk-navbar').each(function() {

   $toggle = $(this).find('.uk-navbar-toggle.uk-search-icon'); // change this line

  if ( $(this).closest('.kiwi-topbar-nav').length ) {     // change this to closest (as parent means direct parent - your div is a grandparent) and check against the length to see if it exists
     $toggle.attr('target', '.kiwi-topbar-nav');
  } else if ( $(this).closest('.kiwi-main-nav').length ) {
     $toggle.attr('target', '.kiwi-main-nav');
  } 

});
```

Or you could just use a function to set the attr:

```
$('.uk-navbar-toggle.uk-search-icon').attr('target', function() {
    if ($(this).closest('.kiwi-topbar-nav').length) {  // check if there is a kiwi-topbar-nav 
       return '.kiwi-topbar-nav';                      // returning this sets the target attribute to this value
    } else if ($(this).closest('.kiwi-main-nav').length) {
       return '.kiwi-main-navv';
    }
});
```